# Converting image to byte array, then to int array, then to byte array for image output

Tags: java, arrays, image, rendering

I'm trying to implement a DCT on an image, and so far I have only been able to successfully read an image, grayscale it, turn it into a byte array and then output the byte array as an image. This works fine. However, in order to work on the image I need to convert the byte array to an int array and then back again, and this is where the problem comes in.

This first part reads the image and converts the image to grayscale.

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\A00226084\\Desktop\\image.jpg"));

int width = image.getWidth();
int height = image.getHeight();

for(int i=0; i<height; i++){

    for(int j=0; j<width; j++){

        Color c = new Color(image.getRGB(j, i));
        int red = (int)(c.getRed() * 0.299);
        int green = (int)(c.getGreen() * 0.587);
        int blue = (int)(c.getBlue() *0.114);
        Color newColor = new Color(red+green+blue,

        red+green+blue,red+green+blue);

        image.setRGB(j,i,newColor.getRGB());
    }
}
```

This part converts the image to a byte array.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", baos);
byte[] pixels = baos.toByteArray();
```

This part then converts the byte array to an int array. I have manually done the wrapping because nothing else worked.

```
for(int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i ++){
    if(pixels[i] < 0){
        byteConverted[i] = 127 + (128 - (pixels[i] * -1));
    }else{
        byteConverted[i] = pixels[i];

    }
}
```

This part converts the int array back to a byte array, somewhere between the byte > int and int > byte conversions that everything goes wrong. I have output both the before and after byte array to a file and they are identical, so I don't know why I get 'image == null' instead of the image.

```
for(int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i ++){
    if(byteConverted[i] > 127){
        pixels[i] = (byte) ( -128 + (byteConverted[i] - 127));
    }else{
        pixels[i] = (byte) byteConverted[i];
    }
}
write2("final byte array.txt", pixels);

ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(pixels);

try {
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(bais);
    System.out.println("Image Out");
    System.out.println(pixels.length);
    ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", new File("C:\\Users\\A00226084\\Desktop\\newImage.jpg"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: what image are you getting null where is this 'image == null'

Comment: image == null is the output from the console when the conversion fails.

Comment: ok and it relates to which image : BufferedImage img ? can you show where this error is coming from: it should show on the error message

Comment: I have now got it to give me an image now, and it doesn't show any errors, but the image is just lines of colours that make no sense, as the image I am working on is already grayscale. When I cut out the byte to int conversion it gives me back the image I put in to begin with, so what I am asking is is there a way to convert to int and then back to byte? I understand there are errors when converting from int to byte unless you do it properly but I have tried every other solution I found on the internet.

Comment: when you cut the int to byte you lost already the info - so you need to explain whats you purpose here what do you want to do: convert color to gray and then gray to color? impossible - explain what you are after overall

Comment: any way I suggest you close this down repackage your question (as it seems has been shifted) and repost a clear question